# Issue with secant root finding c++

Tags: c++, methods

I am trying to wirte a program for school that will use the secant root finding method. The equation is:

> ( v / b ) ^2sin(alpha)= kr * Ts^4 +Uc *Ts -q

and I have to find Ts.

Unfortunately the example i have been using as my base is not working for me :. The root it gives is -1.QNAN or something along those lines so i have a mistake in the secant method somewhere, I am a novice at C++ so i am having a lot of trouble fixing this. Any help will be appreciated, also if someone can tell me the codes to make it easier to post code, i would greatly appreciate it. Thanks
here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void secant (double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, int);

double fx(double, double, double, double, double, double, double);

const double tol=0.0001;    // Tolerance for convergence

const int max_iter=50;      // Maximum iterations allowed

int main ()
{
    double kr, uc, q, b, radians, Ts, x0, x1, root;
    int iteration; 
    const double PI = 4.0*atan(1.0);

    ifstream datain ("shuttle.txt");
    ofstream dataout ("results.txt");

    datain >> kr >> uc >> q >> b;

    int velocity = 16000;
    double angle =10;

    x0= 1000;
    x1 = 200;

    for (int velocity = 16000; velocity <= 17500; velocity += 500) {
        for (int angle = 10; angle <= 70; angle += 15) {
            radians= angle * PI/180  ;

            cout << velocity << endl;
            cout << radians << endl;
            cout << angle << endl;

           secant (angle, radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, Ts, x0, x1, root, iteration);    
        }
    }
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

void secant(double angle, double radians, double velocity, double kr, double uc, double q, double b, double Ts, double x0, double x1, double root, int iteration) 
{
    double xnminus1, xnplus1, xn;
    iteration=0; 
    xnminus1=x0;
    xn=x1;

    do
    {
        ++iteration;
        xnplus1 = xn - fx(kr, uc, Ts, q, velocity, radians, xn)*(xn-xnminus1)/
                  (fx(kr, uc, Ts, q, velocity, radians,xn)-fx(kr, uc, Ts, q, velocity, radians,xnminus1));

        cout<<"x"<<iteration+1<<" = "<<xnplus1<<endl;

        xnminus1 = xn;

        xn=xnplus1;

    }  

    while ((fabs(fx(kr, uc, Ts, q, velocity, radians, xnplus1)) >= tol )&& (iteration < max_iter))
        ;    
    root=xnplus1;  

    cout<<"\nThe root is = "<<root<<endl;
    cout<<"The number of iterations was = "<<iteration<<endl;
    cout<<"The value of f(x) at the root = "<<fx(kr, uc, Ts, q, velocity, radians, root) <<endl<<endl;    
}

double fx(double kr, double uc, double Ts, double q, double velocity, double b, double radians)
{
    return kr * pow(Ts, 4.0) + uc * Ts - q - pow(velocity/b, 2.0) * sin(radians);
}
```

Comment: To format code in a question, read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: I m looking for someone to help me fin whats wrong with my code, because my secant method isnt working and i dont know whats wrong.

Comment: Haven't you already asked this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944986/help-with-secant-root-finding-c

Comment: yes, but that was how to format it, now i am having trouble debugging it

Answer (score 0):

You use Ts without defining it.  Funny that it is highlighted in blue... I think there is a senior SO user chuckling to himself somewhere...

Comment: ohhh, I am trying to solve for Ts, so if i just change Ts to x it should work right?

Comment: @Brian The name has nothing to do with it.  Just follow the usage of 'Ts' from the moment you declare it.  You pass it by value to secant(), which in turn passes it by value to fx().  It is evaluated in 'pow(Ts, 4.0) without every having been defined first.  Also, since you never assign anything to Ts, it's not clear at all how you're trying to solve for it.

Comment: how would i define it if i dont know what it is?

Comment: @Brian : Think about that question in an algebraic context and you may realize how silly it sounds ;-]

Comment: @Brian I see... You need to start with a guess, keep track of prediction error, and adjust Ts with each iteration so as to keep pushing the error down until it's below tol.  You should really need to see your instructor about this or read the book though, doing as much work as it would take to get your program to work as intended is a bit much for SO.